# WSO2-APIM - Build from source (v1.9.1)

Tags: git, maven, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I like to customize to login and the admin console page of the WSO2-APIManager (v 1.9.1), APIM. I would also like to make/build the APIM into a microservice using a fat-jar, since I need to build from source.

This are my questions:

1. Since I like to build the APIM from source. The documentation (http://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Building+from+Source) say that you have to download the "WSO2 Carbon Kernel" but how to I download the correct kernel version (http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) with git? There is no branch nor tag with kernel version 4.2.0.
2. What's the purpose of downloading the kernel? Do I need the kernel to modify the login&admin pages?
3. Do I need to compile, build and install the carbon kernel in my local maven repo before building the APIM?
4. Cloning the repo (https ://github.com/wso2/product-apim) and trying to build (without building the kernel first) results in an error:

   ```
   [INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-03T18:25:24+01:00
   [INFO] Final Memory: 58M/980M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:p2-repo-gen (2-p2-repo-generation) on project am-p2-profile: Error occured when processing the Feature Artifact: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt:org.wso2.carbon.forum.server.feature:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
   ERROR: Could not find artifact org.wso2.carbon.apimgt:org.wso2.carbon.forum.server.feature:zip:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/)
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
   [ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.wso2.carbon.apimgt -DartifactId=org.wso2.carbon.forum.server.feature -Dversion=2.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile=/path/to/file
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
   [ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.wso2.carbon.apimgt -DartifactId=org.wso2.carbon.forum.server.feature -Dversion=2.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] org.wso2.carbon.apimgt:org.wso2.carbon.forum.server.feature:zip:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
   [ERROR] wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
   [ERROR] wso2.releases (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
   [ERROR] wso2.snapshots (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/, releases=false, snapshots=true),
   [ERROR] central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
   ```

Comment: You might be checkout the master branch. That should be why you have snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download the carbon-kernel just to build the API Manager. Carbon-Kernel is the core module/platform for all of the WSO2 products.

Please follow the steps to build the API Manager from source code.

1. [carbon-apimgt](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt) repo has all the components related to API Manager which are reused by other WSO2 products. You have to checkout [`carbon-apimgt-v1.9.1`](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/carbon-apimgt-v1.9.1) tag for API Manager 1.9.1
2. Build this component repo using `mvn clean install`
3. [product-apim](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim) repo has the neccessary artifacts for the API Manager product. For API Manager 1.9.1, you have to checkout [`v1.9.1`](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v1.9.1) tag
4. Build the repo using `mvn clean install`

Comment: using mvn 3.3.3 and oracle java 1.7.55 on a macosx. checkout carbon-apimnt (git clone <carbon-apimgt repo>; git checkout -b carbonapimv191 carbon-apimgt-v1.9.1) and build (mvn clean install) but got 2 failing test in Apache Synapse - Non-blocking HTTP/s Transport ..... FAILURE [01:21 min]. Results :

Failed tests: 
  testCRLPathValidation(org.apache.synapse.transport.certificatevalidation.RevocationVerificationTest)
  testOCSPPathValidation(org.apache.synapse.transport.certificatevalidation.RevocationVerificationTest)

Tests run: 9, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: for the product-apim I get failure at [INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Based on product backend Test Module FAILURE [ 24.358 s]  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) on project org.wso2.carbon.am.integration.backend.test: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test failed: There was an error in the forked process ...java.lang.RuntimeException: Error on initializing test environment ... Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: store.am.wso2.com

Comment: @carestra, Please use maven version  3.0.5. There was a known issue with maven latest version, which will be fixed in next release.

Comment: using **maven 3.0.5 & oracle java1.7.55 on macosx**.  checkout carbon-apimgt (git clone <carbon-apimgt repo>; git checkout release-1.9.1; git checkout -b carbonapimgt191 carbon-apimgt-v1.9.1)  and build (**mvn clean install**) but got 2 failing test in Apache Synapse - Non-blocking HTTP/s Transport ..... FAILURE [01:21 min]. Results : Failed tests: testCRLPathValidation(org.apache.synapse.transport.certificatevalidation.Revocat‌​ionVerificationTest) testOCSPPathValidation(org.apache.synapse.transport.certificatevalidation.Revoca‌​tionVerificationTest)

Comment: using **maven 3.0.5 & oracle java1.7.55 on macosx**.  checkout carbon-apimgt (git clone <carbon-apimgt repo>; git checkout release-1.9.1; git checkout -b carbonapimgt191 carbon-apimgt-v1.9.1)  and build with skipping test (**mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true**) carbon-apimgt got build. Does not feel god skipping test!!

Comment: using **maven 3.0.5 & oracle java1.7.55 on macosx**. checkout product-apim (git clone <product-apim repo>; git checkout 1.9.x; git checkout -b apim191 v1.9.1) and build (**mvn clean install**) but exception in [INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Based on product backend Test Module  FAILURE [14.801s] INFO  [org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender] - Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://store.am.wso2.com:443/services/AuthenticationAdmin]
java.net.UnknownHostException: store.am.wso2.com
.. [ERROR] Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: store.am.wso2.com any idea why unknownhost?? @abimarank

Comment: using **maven 3.0.5 & oracle java1.7.55 on macosx**. checkout product-apim (git clone <product-apim repo>; git checkout 1.9.x; git checkout -b apim191 v1.9.1) and build (**mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true**) product-apim got build. It does not feel god to skip tests!!

Comment: If I build the carbon-apimgt & product-apim succesfully, then how do I start the api-manager? No jar- nor zip file is produce in target-folder. If I try the product-apim/config/wso2server.sh I got error Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager     Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap